# Get child and parent of category

Tags: magento2, category-products

im new bie about magento and im facing an issue:
For example: in my system have Category 1(id=1) -> category 11(id=2) -> category111(id=3), category 112(id=4) , category 113(id=5).
So i finding the solution: if i have id of category 11(2) how can i get all id related with this category.
The expected result be like:[1,2,3,4,5]. if category111 or the other (level 3 ) have subcategory it also appear in the result.
Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get all subcategories of parent category using category id

First of all add **CategoryRepository** in construct:

```
<?php
    protected $categoryRepository;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
    ) {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    }

    $categoryId = [YOUR_CATEGORY_ID];
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
    $subCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
    foreach($subCategories as $subCategory) {
        echo $subCategory->getName();

        /* For Sub Categories */
        if($subcategorie->hasChildren()) {
            $childCategoryObj = $this->categoryRepository->get($subCategory->getId());
            $childSubcategories = $childCategoryObj->getChildrenCategories();
            foreach($childSubcategories as $childSubcategory) {
                 echo 'Sub Category' . $childSubcategory->getName();
            }
        }

        /* For parent categories */
        if ($category->getParentIds) {
           $parentCategories = $category->getParentIds();
           foreach($parentCategories as $parentCategory) {
             echo 'Parent Category' . $parentCategory->getName();
           }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If having the issue in getting parents and children categories from a category in magento2 then no need to worry about this.Here we will see how to get parents and children categories from a category in Magento2.

```
<?php
protected $categoryFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
) {
    $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
}

public function getChildrenCategoriesById($categoryId)
{
    $category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
    $parentCategories = $category->getParentCategories();
    $parentCategoryIds = [];
    $childIds = [];
    foreach ($parentCategories as $parentCategory) {
        $parentCategoryIds[$parentCategory->getId()] = $parentCategory->getName();
    }
    $childrenCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
    foreach ($childrenCategories as $key => $category){
        $childIds[$category->getId()] = $category->getName();
    }
}
```

?>